# Getting value from top of IL stack using IL Emit

Tags: c#, reflection, cil, reflection.emit

I have a `LocalBuilder`, which is essentially an array. I can use it in IL just fine, and I can load it's length using `OpCodes.Ldlen`. I was just wondering, if there is any way to get the length from top of stack to some actual variable. I am looking for something like

```cs
int lengthVariable = 0;

IL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc, arr);
IL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldlen);
IL.Emit(??????, lengthVariable);
```

I want to get this variable so that I can run a loop based on array's length. I know I can create a loop in IL, but I thought it would be a lot more convenient if this was possible.

Edit: What I'm trying to do over here is

- Call an external method (which returns array).
- Perform some action on all the elements of that array. Currently, I am doing this by having two copies of of array (IL and non-IL). Using the non-IL copy, I get the length, and then perform the action n number of times.

The problem with this is that I now have to call the external method twice. I was hoping that I could get the length from IL array so that I can loop over it directly, without calling the external method twice. I know I can write a for loop in IL, but I was kind of avoiding writing branching statements of IL.

Comment: `lengthVariable` doesn't live in the generated code, it lives in the generating code. All you can use is its value, you cannot get any runtime reference to it because it's not there at runtime. You can generate code that passes things to and fro using method parameters and return values, though.

Comment: I think a good question to ask at this point is, what are you actually trying to *achieve*? What problem are you trying to solve? *You* declared the `LocalBuilder`, and it's only manipulated from IL which *you* wrote. Surely you know its length?

Comment: @canton7 This Array would actually be populated by calling some other existing methods which return arrays. I simply store them into `LocalBuilder`s so that I can access them later. That's why I don't know the exact length of the Array.

Comment: @Crimson7 Can you share the equivalent C# code that you're trying to generate? How would the equivalent C# code access your `lengthVariable` variable?

Comment: Could you share your current code? It's not clear how calling the external method twice is helping you here.

Comment: @canton7 I basically had a regular copy of array and one copy of array in IL. I used the regular copy to get count and basically avoided looping over IL copy by unfolding it (Length used here). I went head with @Marc Gravell's approach to write the actual loop as I figured there was no way around it. Currently I am looking at `Sigil` as he suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't populate your local `lengthVariable` like that - it runs in a completely separate scope / stack-frame. However, you could change your method (`DynamicMethod` or `MethodBuilder`) to *return* it, then create a delegate to your new method as a `Func<int>`, and invoke it.

Then your last line would be `IL.Emit(Opcodes.Ret);`, to return the single value on the local stack. Alternatively, you could store the value into an instance or static field, with `Opcodes.Stfld` or `Opcodes.Stsfld`.

---

Following discussion in comments, it seems that the remark

> I know I can write a for loop in IL, but I was kind of avoiding writing branching statements of IL.

in the question may be surmountable; `foreach` *isn't really* all that tricky - the final IL you're after is obtainable [by decompiling existing code](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA0AXEBLANgHwAEAmARgFgAoQgZgAIS6BhOgbyrs4fsJToFkAFNgB2GANoBdOgEMoUAJRsOXVQDNoMGWAAWwsXWyGRs+QpWrLdACIQAKjpgPRAc2EKA3BboBfb4VIkBj5bBycdV30MQwVWP0ofIA=), which leaves the only really *tricky* bit the handling of labels for the actual branch targets - but that just means calling `.DefineLabel()` to *declare them* - you can use them as targets before you know where they'll be jumping to - and `.MarkLabel()` to *position them* (once only). It isn't quite *direct* IL (it uses an abstraction layer), but you can see this approach being used [here](https://github.com/protobuf-net/protobuf-net/blob/2.4.1/src/protobuf-net/Serializers/ArrayDecorator.cs#L123-L156) - in particular, note that it uses `DefineLabel()` ahead of time, and marks the destinations later at `MarkLabel`.

Comment: My entire codebase is based on `TypeBuilder` and `IL`. I'm not sure if I can use `DynamicMethod` with that. If I were to use `MethodBuilder` to get a value from IL, could you give me an example on how I would do that

Comment: @Crimson7 that's fine; `MethodBuilder` is fine here (and more powerful than `DynamicMethod`, in a few ways); it is hard to be specific without a concrete example, but it *sounds* like you just want to set the return type, which you can do in `DefineMethod`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.typebuilder.definemethod?view=netframework-4.8#System_Reflection_Emit_TypeBuilder_DefineMethod_System_String_System_Reflection_MethodAttributes_System_Type_System_Type___

Comment: @Crimson7 I have extensive knowledge of these APIs, so I can almost certainly help - I'm just vague on the specifics of what you're asking!

Comment: The idea is, I would be calling a bunch of external methods (which I don't have control of, but know where they exist) and get the return value and perform some operations. One of such functions return an array. I need to perform some operation on all elements of this array. Currently, I am getting a "non-IL" copy of array and an "IL-copy" and via the "non-IL" copy, I know what the length is. But the problem is, those methods are called twice now. I need this in IL because I have to create a dynamic type. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Crimson7 I would say that the best place to start here would be: write the simplest useful version, **as though you were writing it all in c#**; imagine that the dynamic type existed in C#, just for now (yes, I know it won't really). Now: compile that, and look at what it did. Use that for your template. I do this *all the time* (I maintain a few libraries that make extensive use of this kind of code). https://sharplab.io is perfect for this kind of thing (change the "Results" drop-down to IL)

Comment: @Crimson7 this will achieve two things: 1) it'll clarify what is/isn't going to be possible in terms of how to interact between the generated type and the main C# code, and 2) it'll tell you exactly what ops you want

Comment: I already do this and that's how I got till here. Now, in this particular case, I have 3 options: 1. Have two copies of array (IL and NonIL) so that I can iterate over them (already doing this). 2. Write a for loop or foreach loop in IL (kind of avoiding this, but this is fallback). 3. Somehow get the length of array out from top of stack so that I can loop in actual code, and output unrolled IL.

Comment: @Crimson7 you probably don't have two copies of the *array*; you likely have two copies of the *reference* to the same array; that's fine - that's cheap. A 4th option might be: invoke a generic method that does the loop internally; however, writing a `foreach` loop on an array is pretty simple IL; random no-context example: https://github.com/protobuf-net/protobuf-net/blob/2.4.1/src/protobuf-net/Serializers/ArrayDecorator.cs#L123-L156

Comment: @Crimson7 (`Compiler.Local` here is just an abstraction over `LocalBuilder`, and `CompilerContext` is just an abstraction over `ILGenerator`)

Comment: It's really actually two copies of Array, I actually checked. On the other hand, that link you gave looks promising. Let me go through it. Thanks!

Comment: @Crimson7 here's sharplap.io showing something similar: https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA0AXEBLANgHwAEAmARgFgAoQgZgAIS6BhOgbyrs4fsJToFkAFNgB2GANoBdOgEMoUAJRsOXVQDNoMGWAAWwsXWyGRs+QpWrLdACIQAKjpgPRAc2EKA3BboBfb4VIkBj5bBycdV30MQwVWP0ofIA=

Comment: Yeah, looking into something similar. If you would update your answer with a foreach loop with an explanation, I would accept it.

Comment: @Crimson7 as a final passing note: if you're sick of `InvalidProgramException`: I recommend [Sigil](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Sigil/) - basic selling point: "kinda like IL generator, but a: it' makes it hard to make mistakes, and b: when you *do*, it tells you what, rather than killing the process" (and no: that isn't the abstraction I'm using in my code, because I'm a hypocrite)